# Url Mapping in Ember js

Tags: ember.js, url-routing, ember-cli

I have two separate routes parking and Car (not a nested route).

Parking route has dynamic segment like parking id `/parking/21` and 
Car has car name and id  `/car/ford/12`

*Router.js:*

```
Router.map( function() {
   this.route("parking", { path: "/parking/:parkingId"})
   this.route("car", { path: "/car/:carName/:carId" })
});
```

when transition from parking route to car route, i need a url like `(/parking/21/ford/12)`

Comment: you have that url. What is not working? Maybe you want to join the ember community Discord channel?

Comment: Have you tried `transitionTo('car', 'ford', '21')`? And if you want a parking before you need to nest the `car` route under `parking`.

Comment: the car route is not going to be nested under parking,it's a separate route

Comment: But it should be. That's probably your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want nesting, then you need to include the full URL in you `car` route, like so:

```js
Router.map( function() {
   this.route("parking", { path: "/parking/:parkingId"});
   this.route("car", { path: "/parking/:parkingId/car/:carName/:carId" });
});
```

When transitioning to the `car` route, you once again need to pass all three dynamic segments, something like:

```js
<LinkTo @route="car" @models=(array "myParkingId" "myCarName" "myCarId") />
```

Or:

```js
this.router.transitionTo('car', "myParkingId", "myCarName", "myCarId");
```

Comment: Also need a transition to car route without parking details, so
i added this line in my router `this.route("car", { path: "/car/:carName/:carId" }); `
but i can't get when `this.transitionTo("/car/ford/12")`

Comment: you can not add the same route twice with different `path`s. Also it would be `this.transitionTo("car", "ford", "12")`.

Comment: Like mentioned, it would need to be a different route with a different name!

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is to nest the routes:

```
Router.map( function() {
   this.route("parking", { path: "/parking/:parkingId"}, function() {
       this.route("car", { path: "/car/:carName/:carId" })
   });
});
```

Then move your existing logic from the `parking` template to the `parking.index` route. So you have 3 routes:

- `parking`
- `parking.index` with urls like `/parking/1`
- `parking.car` with urls like `/parking/1/car/ford/7`

you will however never be *only* in the `parking` route. You will either be in `parking.index` or `parking.car`.

From the `parking.index` and the `parking.car` route you can access the model of the `parking` route with `this.modelFor('parking')` from the `Route`.

You can transition with `transitionTo('parking', 1)` or `transitionTo('parking.car', 1, 'ford', 7)`.

Comment: Is it possible to make it without the nested route? I introduced certain cases similar to this and planning to introduce new cases in the future. My point is, changing the path every time is not efficient.

Comment: Your route nesting should reflect your URL structure. Thats the point of it. The other thing is to just have all 3 dynamic segments: `this.route("car", { path: "/parking/:parkingId/car/:carName/:carId" })`